# I'm trying to use aggregation but I think I get it wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, aggregation

So I wrote a code with a Bank class that has a validation method and a SavingAccount class that has a withdraw method, and I'm trying to use aggregation to associate them both, but it isn't working. The validation is validating everything. The focus should be in the Bank class and the SavingAccount class and at the end I put the instance that shouldn't work (acc1.withdraw()), I put the others class so that you can try out the code, anyway here is the code :

**Expected behavior**: Without calling the add_acc() function, the validation should return False and it shouldn't let me use the withdraw() function.

**Actual behavior**: I'm able to withdraw() even when the add_acc() wasn't called

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Account(ABC):
    def __init__(self, agency, acc_number, balance):
        self.agency = agency
        self.acc_number = acc_number
        self.balance = balance

    @abstractmethod
    def withdraw(self, value):
        pass


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


class Bank:
    def __init__(self):
        self.account = {}

    def add_acc(self, client, account):
        self.account.update({f'{client}': account})

    def validation(self):
        if self.account:
            for acc in self.account:
                if acc in self.account:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False


class SavingAccount(Account):
    if Bank.validation:
        def withdraw(self, value):
            if self.balance < value:
                print('Insufficient funds.')
                return
            self.balance -= value
            print(f'{value} dollars withdrawn. Current balance: {self.balance}$')
    else:
        print('Account information invalid.')


class Client(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, acc_type):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.acc_type = acc_type

bank1 = Bank()
acc1 = SavingAccount(33333, 33330, 2000)
client1 = Client('Matthew', 40, acc1)
acc1.withdraw(500)   # Right here this shouldn't work without me adding bank1.add_acc()
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). "The code is a bit extensive" clearly calls out that this posting is not yet ready to be a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't saw this post, I'll edit it right now

Comment: Should I delete the post and ask the question again or the edit is fine ?

Comment: I edited a typo also

Comment: Don't you have to call add accunt function

Comment: Yeah I should have to call the function, but if I don't call it the validation should return False and don't let me withdraw the money from the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues with your code.

The first is that your implementation of `SavingsAccount` is seriously flawed. You're checking if `Bank.validate` is truthy, rather than calling it. But even if you did call it, it wouldn't make any sense at the location you have the call. You are attempting to do the validation *when the class is defined*, not when you create an instance of the class, or try to withdraw funds. That doesn't make any sense. The concept of savings accounts (i.e. the definition of the class) should be able exist even if there haven't been any banks founded yet. Do the validation some time later! And probably you need to be validating with *some specific instance* of the `Bank` class, not with the `Bank` class directly.

The second issue is that your `Bank.validate` method doesn't do anything useful. It loops over all the keys in the `self.accounts` dictionary, but then just checks the first one to see if it's in the dictionary (which is always will be, if you reached that part of the code), and then returns. Probably you want that function to be checking *one specific account*, not checking in general for arbitrary accounts. That account (or an account number, or something) should probably be an argument to the function.

Comment: Good work -- I read this and deleted my 3/4-finished answer on the same two points.

Comment: Thanks ! So just to check if I get it right because I'm new to programming. I should fix the ```Bank.validate``` method to something that checks if a key, value pair is in the dict without looping over it, then call this validation method when I call the withdraw method or ```Bank``` _instance_ ? What I'm thinking right now is to put validation as a param to the withdraw function and call the ```validation``` function to return ```True``` or ```False``` before I call the ```withdraw```function and because it's a param assigned to a variable it could be set without using comp. or inheritance.

Comment: There was another error, in ```add_acc``` I had  this line ```self.account.update({f'{client}': account})``` with client in a f string, after I removed it and fixed the ```validation``` method and put the conditional when I call the ```withdraw``` method everything worked fine. Thanks again Blckknght you helped me a lot.